# EF subsequent migration - fill new table with data

Tags: entity-framework, data-migration

I've created a new class, and EF will create a migration code when I'll do `add-migration` in Package Manager Console. Since this table is a classifier, I want to populate it with data and include this data in migration. I cannot use `Seed` method, since i'll be using my generated migration on production database later on.

Where should I hardcode the values for this table? I can edit the generated migration cs file, but this seems an inelegant solution. Could you recommend more proper place to define the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you're goal is to populate your table for development/testing, there's no reason you shouldn't do you data seeding via the `Seed` method. You could always wrap the seed code for this table with an `if` block that checks your connection string values.

**Edit:**
If you plan to populate your table in your production database with the same data, it would certainly make sense to do so in the `Up` method of that specific migration that creates the table.

Comment: Not exactly - my goal is to populate the table for production also. If it was for dev/testing only I would put the data in Seed method.

Comment: In that case, you would be better off adding your hard-coded data within your migration class.

Comment: In the end, i've added the data inside the generated migration script- it seems there are no significantly better ways to do this.